# Save a document library template with pages that has web parts and then create a new library

Tags: web-part, document-library, web-part-page

I have a document library with a few pages and each page has some web parts [webpart are custom web part]

But if I create a document library template (with content) and then create a new document library using that template in the same site all the pages are empty (no web parts). How should I solve this, to be able to keep the web parts in the new library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you figured out your issue? Did you try what Fox recommended?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like what you need is a Site Template.

Please explain how your document Library is setup. Have you setup actual web parts on the different views of the doc library?

Example: Allitems.aspx has a couple of webparts, NewItem.aspx has a couple of webparts?

If so, saving the doc lib as a template should work.

If not, and you created normal pages, they wont be included when you save the library as a template.

Please explain more and i'll see if I can help :-)